# PHP Prepared statement login

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, passwords, sql-injection

I'm in the process of adding password hashing and SQL injection defenses into my Login system. Currently, I've ran into an error.

```
    <?php
session_start(); //start the session for user profile page

define('DB_HOST','localhost'); 
define('DB_NAME','test'); //name of database
define('DB_USER','root'); //mysql user
define('DB_PASSWORD',''); //mysql password

$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test','root','');

function SignIn($con){
    $user = $_POST['user']; //user input field from html
    $pass = $_POST['pass']; //pass input field from html
    if(isset($_POST['user'])){ //checking the 'user' name which is from Sign-in.html, is it empty or have some text
        $query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM UserName where userName = :user") or die(mysqli_connect_error());
        $query->bindParam(':user',$user);
        $query->execute();

        $username = $query->fetchColumn(1);
        $pw = $query->fetchColumn(2);//hashed password in database
        //check username and password
        if($user==$username && password_verify($pass, $pw)) {
            // $user and $pass are from POST
            // $username and $pw are from the rows

            //$_SESSION['userName'] = $row['pass'];
            echo "Successfully logged in.";
        }

        else { 
            echo "Invalid."; 
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "INVALID LOGIN";
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    SignIn($con);
}
?>
```

In the above code, when I enter a valid username and password, the system prints out "Invalid". It could be a error in the password_verify() in the if statement(because if I remove it, I login successfully). I'm pretty sure I've done the preparing, binding and execution of the query properly? Does anyone know why it is doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not verify the password at the DB level?

Comment: @chris85 afaik MySQL have no way of validating Bcrypt.

Comment: Is the value of $pass what you expect? Is the dB saving a hash when you create the password?

Comment: Not sure what Bcrypt is but use it before you send it to the db. Something like `$pass = bcrypt($_POST['pass']); //pass input field from html`

Comment: @chris85 Bcrypt is the default and recommended hash routine for password storage in PHP. You can't do it before because each time you hash it generates a unique salt that is stored as part of the hash. You need to fetch the hash and validate against what the user posted.

Comment: I have another registration script that hashes the password and stores them in the database.

Comment: Aha, thanks @JimL, just read up on it.

Comment: Has fetching data as an associative array fixed your issue or are you still having trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
// it will be an array('name' => 'John', 'password_hash' => 'abcd')
// or FALSE if user not found
$storedUser = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

instead of

```
$username = $query->fetchColumn(1);
$pw = $query->fetchColumn(2);
```

Because fetchColumn moves cursor of result. So first call extracts 1 column of first row, and second call will extract data from SECOND row!

Comment: It is a good recommendation, but it in no way answers what OP asked.

Comment: it's not just code-style issue. fetchColumn moves cursor of result. So first call extracts 1 column of first row, and second call will extract data from SECOND row! It's real mistake.

Comment: Yep. Its works now, Thanks! And also what does it mean when fetchColumn moves cursor of result?

Comment: for example, your query returns 3 rows: (id=1), (id=2), (id=3). You call $query->fetchColumn(0) the first time and receive value "1", then you call $query->fetchColumn(0) the second time and it's returns value "2". It's a value of second row. See details here http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php

Answer (score 2):

You're doing a SELECT *, and using fetchColumn, so the results are dependent of the returned columns order. You should either select the specific columns you need, or fetch the whole row as an associative array , and access it by column name.

There are other two issues that you should fix:

- You shouldn't be using mysqli_connect_error() as you're using PDO. The right function would be [$con->errorInfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php).
- You're defining some constants with the connection settings, yet you don't use them on the PDO() call, repeating the values instead.