# Sign in page accepting any password

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a xamp based webserver and I installed attendance system , I have 10 users registered to enter their attendance by login individually... issue is in login page accept any password and not giving error that password is wrong. Like you enter user id john@abcd.com & password gfjhgh its accept and entered to index page , the original password is 123456 but its accept every thing you type. Please tell me how to solve. It should says that you entered wrong password and can not login.

Code is below:

```
// Account Log In
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'signIn') {
    if($_POST['emailAddy'] == '') {
        $msgBox = alertBox($accEmailReq, "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>", "danger");
    } else if($_POST['password'] == '') {
        $msgBox = alertBox($accPassReq, "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>", "danger");
    } else {
        $usrEmail = htmlspecialchars($_POST['emailAddy']);

        $check = "SELECT userId, userFirst, userLast, isActive FROM users WHERE userEmail = '".$usrEmail."'";
        $res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $check) or die('-1' . mysqli_error());
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($res);

        if ($count > 0) {
            // If the account is Active - Allow the login
            if ($row['isActive'] == '1') {
                $userEmail = htmlspecialchars($_POST['emailAddy']);
                $password = encodeIt($_POST['password']);

                if($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("
                                        SELECT
                                            userId,
                                            userEmail,
                                            userFirst,
                                            userLast,
                                            location,
                                            superUser,
                                            isAdmin
                                        FROM
                                            users
                                        WHERE
                                            userEmail = ?
                                            AND password = ?
                ")) {
                    $stmt -> bind_param("ss",
                                        $userEmail,
                                        $password
                    );
                    $stmt -> execute();
                    $stmt -> bind_result(
                                $userId,
                                $userEmail,
                                $userFirst,
                                $userLast,
                                $location,
                                $superUser,
                                $isAdmin
                    );
                    $stmt -> fetch();
                    $stmt -> close();

                    if (!empty($userId)) {
                        if(!isset($_SESSION))session_start();
                        $_SESSION['tz']['userId']       = $userId;
                        $_SESSION['tz']['userEmail']    = $userEmail;
                        $_SESSION['tz']['userFirst']    = $userFirst;
                        $_SESSION['tz']['userLast']     = $userLast;
                        $_SESSION['tz']['location']     = $location;
                        $_SESSION['tz']['superUser']    = $superUser;
                        $_SESSION['tz']['isAdmin']      = $isAdmin;

                        // Add Recent Activity
                        $activityType = '1';
                        $tz_uid = $userId;
                        $activityTitle = $userFirst.' '.$userLast.' '.$accSignInAct;
                        updateActivity($tz_uid,$activityType,$activityTitle);

                        // Update the Last Login Date for User
                        $sqlStmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users SET lastVisited = NOW() WHERE userId = ?");
                        $sqlStmt->bind_param('s', $userId);
                        $sqlStmt->execute();
                        $sqlStmt->close();

                        header('Location: index.php');
                    } else {
                        // Add Recent Activity
                        $activityType = '0';
                        $tz_uid = '0';
                        $activityTitle = $accSignInErrAct;
                        updateActivity($tz_uid,$activityType,$activityTitle);

                        $msgBox = alertBox($accSignInErrMsg, "<i class='fa fa-warning'></i>", "warning");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Add Recent Activity
                $activityType = '0';
                $tz_uid = $row['userId'];
                $activityTitle = $row['userFirst'].' '.$row['userLast'].' '.$signInUsrErrAct;
                updateActivity($tz_uid,$activityType,$activityTitle);

                // If the account is not active, show a message
                $msgBox = alertBox($inactAccMsg, "<i class='fa fa-warning'></i>", "warning");
            }
        } else {
            // Add Recent Activity
            $activityType = '0';
            $tz_uid = '0';
            $activityTitle = $noAccSignInErrAct;
            updateActivity($tz_uid,$activityType,$activityTitle);

            // No account found
            $msgBox = alertBox($noAccSignInErrMsg, "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>", "danger");
        }
    }
}

// Reset Account Password
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'resetPass') {
    // Validation
    if ($_POST['accountEmail'] == "") {
        $msgBox = alertBox($accEmailReq, "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>", "danger");
    } else {
        $usrEmail = htmlspecialchars($_POST['accountEmail']);

        $query = "SELECT userEmail FROM users WHERE userEmail = ?";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$usrEmail);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($emailUser);
        $stmt->store_result();
        $numrows = $stmt->num_rows();

        if ($numrows == 1) {
            // Generate a RANDOM Hash for a password
            $randomPassword = uniqid(rand());

            // Take the first 8 digits and use them as the password we intend to email the Employee
            $emailPassword = substr($randomPassword, 0, 8);

            // Encrypt $emailPassword for the database
            $newpassword = encodeIt($emailPassword);

            //update password in db
            $updatesql = "UPDATE users SET password = ? WHERE userEmail = ?";
            $update = $mysqli->prepare($updatesql);
            $update->bind_param("ss",
                                    $newpassword,
                                    $usrEmail
                                );
            $update->execute();

            $qry = "SELECT userId, userFirst, userLast, isAdmin FROM users WHERE userEmail = '".$usrEmail."'";
            $results = mysqli_query($mysqli, $qry) or die('-2' . mysqli_error());
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
            $theUser = $row['userId'];
            $isAdmin = $row['isAdmin'];
            $userName = $row['userFirst'].' '.$row['userLast'];

            if ($isAdmin == '1') {
                // Add Recent Activity
                $activityType = '3';
                $activityTitle = $userName.' '.$admPassResetAct;
                updateActivity($theUser,$activityType,$activityTitle);
            } else {
                // Add Recent Activity
                $activityType = '3';
                $activityTitle = $userName.' '.$usrPassResetAct;
                updateActivity($theUser,$activityType,$activityTitle);
            }

            $subject = $siteName.' '.$resetPassEmailSub;

            $message = '<html><body>';
            $message .= '<h3>'.$subject.'</h3>';
            $message .= '<p>'.$resetPassEmail1.'</p>';
            $message .= '<hr>';
            $message .= '<p>'.$emailPassword.'</p>';
            $message .= '<hr>';
            $message .= '<p>'.$resetPassEmail2.'</p>';
            $message .= '<p>'.$resetPassEmail3.' '.$installUrl.'sign-in.php</p>';
            $message .= '<p>'.$emailTankYouTxt.'<br>'.$siteName.'</p>';
            $message .= '</body></html>';

            $headers = "From: ".$siteName." <".$siteEmail.">\r\n";
            $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$siteEmail."\r\n";
            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

            mail($usrEmail, $subject, $message, $headers);

            $msgBox = alertBox($resetPassMsg1, "<i class='fa fa-check-square'></i>", "success");
            $stmt->close();
        } else {
            // Add Recent Activity
            $activityType = '1';
            $tz_uid = '0';
            $activityTitle = $resetPassMsgAct;
            updateActivity($tz_uid,$activityType,$activityTitle);

            // No account found
            $msgBox = alertBox($resetPassMsg2, "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>", "danger");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: would be nice if you can only post the relevant code :)

Comment: Mahi provide only relevant code

Comment: i edited and more specific please check and guide me what should change or replace? as i am not a developer please correct all code and give me if u can please

Comment: Check [this](https://file.io/hKp9Wk).

Comment: what's encodeIt() ?

Comment: @OwesomeMahi don't post your full code, edit the code and post the login part only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Prepared statement login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785447/php-prepared-statement-login)

Answer (score 0):

I'm only assuming that the first time you tried to login is that the session was save and you did not destroy the session.

```
if ((isset($_SESSION['tz']['userId'])) && ($_SESSION['tz']['userId'] != '')) {
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

thus making that condition always true.

If you want to prevent/avoid the user in logging in without the valid credentials.

Matching the records in the DB

```
$check = "SELECT userEmail, password FROM users WHERE userEmail = '".$usrEmail."' AND password = '".$password."'";
        $res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $check) or die('-1' . mysqli_error());
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($res);

        if ($count > 0) {
      //match found
          }
       else {
      //no match found or username/password doesn't match
     }
```

Comment: how to avoid/ prevent login with any password? i want user can only login with his specific password

Comment: where i paste your given code and also my db have userEmail not username... so where i write userEmail and where username ,  ( table name is 'users' , username is 'userEmail' , password  is 'password ) please majorlogic edit you post again , and where i put this code in whole page?

Comment: Put it after the conditions email and password are not empty. I edited it again

Comment: thanks a lot for your help but still not working. kindly help me more.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'signIn') {
        if($_POST['emailAddy'] == '') {
            $msgBox = alertBox($accEmailReq, "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>", "danger");
        } else if($_POST['password'] == '') {
            $msgBox = alertBox($accPassReq, "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>", "danger");
        } else {
            $usrEmail = htmlspecialchars($_POST['emailAddy']);
            $password = encodeIt($_POST['password']);

            $check = "SELECT userId, userFirst, userLast, isActive FROM users WHERE userEmail = '".$usrEmail."'";
            $res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $check) or die('-1' . mysqli_error());
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($res);

            if ($count > 0) {
```

Comment: above code is a part of my sign-in.php page, and you can login with abc@abc.com and password "any keyboard entry :( i want to stop this , user is abc@abc.com and password is 123456, but abc@abc.com login with any password like "fgdfg" "fdg" dfgdfgdffsedf343"